# Erase elements from a vector of pointers and deallocate the dynamic memory previously allocated via new operator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I want to show you this very simple example, the purpose is to sort some strings allocated dynamically and clean the duplicates resizing the vector and deallocating useless occupated memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print_v (vector<string *>& v)
{
    cout << "----" << endl;
    for (string*& str : v)
        cout << *str << " ";
    cout << endl << "----" << endl;
}

typedef string * string_ptr;

int main() 
{
    vector<string_ptr> v;
    v.push_back(new string("aba"));
    v.push_back(new string("baba"));
    v.push_back(new string("saba"));
    v.push_back(new string("aba"));
    v.push_back(new string("naba"));
    v.push_back(new string("aba"));
    v.push_back(new string("saba"));
    v.push_back(new string("laba"));

    print_v(v);

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const string_ptr &a, const string_ptr &b){ 
        return a->compare(*b) < 0; 
    });

    auto last = unique(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const string_ptr &a, const string_ptr &b) {
        return a->compare(*b) == 0;
    });

    print_v(v);

    for_each(last, v.end(), [](string_ptr &a){
        delete a;       //if I comment this line everything works "fine"
        a = nullptr;
    });

    v.erase( find(v.begin(), v.end(), nullptr) , v.end() );

    print_v(v);
}
```

Why this kind of stuff didn't work? If I comment the line with `delete` everything works fine but I have of course memory leaks. Another question: if in the signature of the lambda functions I use `string*` (instead of the typedef `string_ptr`) I get nasty compilation errors, why?

Sorry for my bad english, I hope the questions are clear enough.

Comment: It would be much better to just have a `vector<string>`. What do you need the extra dynamic allocation for? Unless you have important reasons not stated/shown here, most of the above code is unnecessary.

Comment: `std::string` is not meant to be used dynamically, you shouldn't try to manage such memory issues by yourself since `std::unique_ptr<T>` already does its job in managing destruction of objects in STL collections. STL already provides 2 data structure to manage unique objects: `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: If this was just an example, why not just use unique_ptr<string>?  It will delete the memory when the element is erased.  Come caution needed however, i.e. std::move required to get it into the array in the first place.

Comment: Maybe read up on what `std::unique` does?

Comment: The items that `std::unique` sticks on the right side of the partition are unspecified values.  You basically can't do anything with them except remove them.  So caling `delete` on these (basically) garbage values is not going to work.  In all of that, why you didn't just use `std::set<std::string>`?  The items are sorted already, and duplicates won't show up.

Comment: My reason for the extra dynamic allocation is the following: I'm building a ternary search tree from an ordered dictionary of strings and my implementattion removes a string from the dictionary each time that string is added in the tst (for run-time space reasons on my poor memory laptop). Just "erasing" the string was not a viable option for me since it modifies the dimension of the vector (I'm building the tst in a recursive way using indexes). The problem exposed here is related on how i get the strings (typically from file and I need to ensure that are sorted and unique)

Comment: @Murray Please see my answer.  If you want to partition off the items you want to delete, you have to use one of the partitioning algorithms and *then* issue a `delete` call on those items.  Using `std::unique` is not the right tool to use since its job is to have items placed on the right side of the partition for later removal.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I saw it, you and user3286661 saved my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the `std::unique` function basically makes those items that are placed on the right-side of the returned iterator zombie elements.  They can be accessed, but they're useless.  That's why your `delete` does not work correctly when you applied it to these items.

If your goal is to partition off the unique items, but at the same time keep their validity, the algorithm function you may want to use is [std::stable_partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), with a usage of `std::set`.  So in place of `std::unique`, you can do the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
//...
std::set<std::string> stringset;
auto last = std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [&stringset](const string_ptr& a) 
{
   if ( stringset.count(*a) )  return false;
    stringset.insert(*a); return true;  
});
```

Basically, we use the `std::set` to store values we initially find.  On subsequent calls to the lambda function, we check for duplicates by querying the `set::count()` function.  If it returns 1, then the item already exists in the set, 0 otherwise.  So to place the duplicate items to the right of the partition, we need to return `false`, and brand new items, we return `true` (and also we add the item to the set if it's a new item).  So basically, we've written a non-destructive version of `std::unique` by using `std::stable_partition`.

Thus this results in the unique items not only being partitioned off to the right of the returned iterator of `std::stable_partition`, those items are perfectly valid and can be used for whatever purpose you see fit (in your case, you wanted to `delete` them).

Note that this works, as shown by this [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a030c4e49ce6ecea)

Also, you could use `std::partition`, but this function does not preserve the relative order of the items.  You may want to use `std::partition` instead, but I am assuming you want to keep the order of the elements.

Comment: `stable_partition` fits perfectly with my needs, thank you very much for pointing out  this function!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're deleting elements which are still pointing to valid string (in your case, one of the unique strings). `unique` function gives the iterator to the element that is just after last element which is not removed. After calling `unique`, you are deleting everything from last -> v.end(). This is deleting some string which is in the unique part of the vector. To make things clear here is the output after sorting:

```
aba 0xca9c20 aba 0xca9d20 aba 0xca9cf0 baba 0xca9c70 laba 0xca9e00 naba 0xca9d50 saba 0xca9cc0 saba 0xca9dd0
```

And after calling `unique`:

```
aba 0xca9c20 baba 0xca9c70 laba 0xca9e00 naba 0xca9d50 saba 0xca9cc0 naba 0xca9d50 saba 0xca9cc0 saba 0xca9dd0
```

Note that I've modified the `print_v` function to also print the addresses of the strings. As you can see, the string **naba** is at a memory location `0xca9d50` and after the last unique element i.e. **saba**, the duplicate string **naba** is exactly the same as the one earlier, i.e. is stored at the same address. So when you're calling `delete`, you're invalidating the first string's address as well. So when you call `print_v` next it sees that the address is invalid and gives you a segfault.

Comment: Ouch, I didn't think about this... now it's clear my error. Thank you!