# How to remove objects and pointers from vector of pointers by object parameter

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of pointers to Event object like this:

```
std::vector <Event*> event_queue_;
```

This is my Event class

```
class Event{
...
bool IsAlarmSensitiveEvent();
bool alarm_sensitive_event_;
...

};
```

I would like to remove pointers from vector of pointers and Event objects when alarm_sensitive_event_ is true.

I tried to do this like this:

```
for (Event* x : event_queue_)
    {

            if (x != nullptr)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < event_queue_.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (event_queue_.at(i)->IsAlarmSensitiveEvent())
                    {

                        std::cout << "Removing event " << event_queue_.at(i)->NameOfEvent() << std::endl;
                        delete event_queue_.at(i);          
                        event_queue_.erase(event_queue_.begin() + i);
                        removed = true;
                    }

                }
            }

    }
```

It is working but I think loop in the loop isn't the best way so I'm looking for something better.

Comment: Are you asking for [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)? Edit : Nevermind, that won't work with raw owning pointers.

Comment: Since you are `delete`ing the pointers in your container that container's pointers clearly have unique ownership of those object. You should be using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Event>>` instead. Owning raw pointers should not be used anymore.

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598883/erase-elements-from-a-vector-of-pointers-and-deallocate-the-dynamic-memory-previ/39599939#39599939).  You could partition off the items you want to call `delete` on, delete them, then remove them from the vector.

Comment: Your loop is incorrect. Think about what happens when you delete an event, you make the event_queue smaller **and** you increment the index. That cannot be right, and it will mean that if you have consecutive items to delete yuo'll miss the second item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598883/erase-elements-from-a-vector-of-pointers-and-deallocate-the-dynamic-memory-previ/39599939#39599939) as a guide, you can partition off the elements to delete first, delete them, then erase them from the vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//…
// Partition the elements to delete (place the items to delete on right side of vector)
auto iter = std::stable_partition(event_queue.begin(), event_queue.end(), 
                                  [](Event *x) { return !x->IsAlarmSensitiveEvent(); });

// Deallocate them
std::for_each(iter, event_queue.end(), [](Event *x) 
             { 
                 std::cout << "Removing event " << x->NameOfEvent() << "\n";
                 delete x;
             });

// Erase them from vector
event_queue.erase(iter, event_queue.end());
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

What if I have `auto* event_queue_ = new vector<Event>` instead of `vector <Event*> event_queue_`?